# Extrinsically flat submanifolds of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $Q$ be a $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. A submanifold $M$ of $Q$ is said to be *extrinsically flat* if $R_{M}(X,Y,Z,W) = R_{Q}(X,Y,Z,W)$ for all $X,Y,Z,W \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, where $R_{M}$ and $R_{Q}$ are the curvature tensors of $M$ and $Q$, respectively.

It is clear that if the rank of the second fundamental form of $M$ is at most one, then by the Gauss equation $M$ is extrinsically flat.

I am wondering about the existence of such type of submanifolds. For instance, the classical *axiom of planes* of Cartan gives obstructions to the existence of “many” totally geodesic submanifolds, as explained below.

Fix $2 \leq r < d-1$. We say that $Q$ satisfies the *axiom of $r$-planes* if for every $p \in Q$ and each $r$-dimensional subspace $\varSigma$ of $T_{p}Q$ there exists a totally geodesic submanifold $S$ such that $T_{p}S = \varSigma$.

**Theorem.** If $Q$ satisfies the axiom of $r$-planes for some $r$, then $Q$ has constant curvature.

**Question**. In general, given a Riemannian manifold $Q$, are extrinsically flat submanifolds of $Q$ plentiful or rare? Is it possible for a Riemannian manifold $Q$ to satisfy the “axiom of extrinsically flat submanifolds” without necessarily having constant curvature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the simplest case, in which $Q$ is a $3$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, then there are plenty of extrinsically flat surfaces $M\subset Q$.  In fact, if one chooses a 'generic' curve $\gamma$ in $Q$ and a 'generic' normal vector field $\nu$ along $\gamma$, then there will be a unique 'extinsically flat' surface $M$ containing $\gamma$ that has $\nu$ as its normal along $\gamma$.

In Cartan's language, the extrinsically flat surfaces in $Q$ depend on two functions of one variable.  This does not depend on any knowledge of the curvature of $Q$.

**Addendum 1:** (7/23/22)  I thought a little more about this and realized that there is a natural conjecture about the existence of 'extrinsically flat' submanifolds.  Here is the statement.

*Conjecture:*  For each $r\ge2$, let $D_r = r^2(r^2{-}1)/12$ be the rank of the Riemann curvature tensor in dimension $r$.  For a Riemannian manifold $Q$ of dimension $d\ge r + D_r$, the PDE for 'extrinsically flat' submanifolds of dimension $r$ is involutive.  In particular, such local submanifolds are just as 'plentiful' in $Q$ as they are in flat $\mathbb{R}^d$.

The intuition for the Conjecture is this:  'Extrinsic flatness of $M\subset Q$ is the requirement that, at each point $x\in M$, the Riemann curvature tensor of $M$ at $x$ should be equal to the restriction of the Riemann curvature tensor of $Q$ at $x$ to $T_xM$.  This is $D_r$ second order PDE on $M$ as a submanifold of $Q$.  Since the $r$-dimensional submanifolds of $Q$ can be represented locally as graphs of $d{-}r$ functions of $r$ variables, this PDE system will be formally 'determined' if $d{-}r = D_r$ and 'overdetermined' if $d{-}r<D_r$.  If the symbol of the PDE system is 'non-degenerate', in the appropriate sense, when $d{-}r = D_r$, then, at least in the real-analytic category, there will be 'plenty' of local solutions.  In fact one would expect the local generality of the solutions in this case to be $2D_r$ functions of $r{-}1$ variables.  Meanwhile, for a 'generic' $Q$ of dimension $d<r + D_r$, one would expect that it would not have any 'extrinsically flat' submanifolds of dimension $r$.

The above conjecture is easily established for $r=2$.  (The case $(r,d)=(2,3)$ is just the statement in the first paragraph.)  The case $(r,d)=(3,9)$ (note that $9 = 3 + D_3$) seems to work, but I haven't checked all of the details, as the algebra is a little tricky.

Also, note that, for the 'overdetermined' non-existence result mentioned above, it is essential that one assume that the metric on $Q$ be 'generic'.  As Cartan showed, if $d=2r$ and $Q$ has constant sectional curvature $c$, then the PDE for $r$-dimensional submanifolds of constant sectional curvature $c$ is involutive, and $2r < r + D_r$ when $r>2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Do you know of any reference where this is proved? I have only seen a proof in the Euclidean case.

Comment: My main motivation for asking the question was in fact to understand whether there was any difference in studying e.g. 3D curves (those having only two nonzero Frenet curvatures) in a three-dimensional manifold rather than in a higher-dimensional one. Given any 3D curve in $M = M^{m > 3}$, if one could cut out a three-dimensional extrinsically flat submanifold containing the curve, then there would be no difference. I know that this is possible when $M$ has constant curvature. Your answer seems to indicate that this is always possible, am I right?

Comment: I had previously asked such question (well, for planar curves) [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/426737/).

Comment: @MK7: I don't know a reference, but, in the real-analytic case, it's an immediate consequence of the Cartan-Kähler theorem applied to the natural (Monge-Ampère) exterior differential system on the (5-dimensional) unit tangent bundle of $Q$. Because the EDS is of null  type (nowhere elliptic or hyperbolic), I think there is a smooth version that is also valid, but, to be frank, I have not checked whether the Goursat invariant of the system vanishes (as it does in the case that $Q$ has constant curvature), and one may need that for the smooth theory.  I'll think more about your other questions.

Comment: Thanks, that would help a lot